# Manhwa where a boy's dad is murdered. He uses a video game screen to control people and get them to answer his questions

Tags: story-identification, manga

I'm looking for a manhwa where a boy's dad gets murdered and he tries to find out who did it. A video game screen appears, and it lets him control people and answer his questions.

Comment: What sort of time period and world was the story set in?